# Enable Postgresql in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I installed `Cygwin` with Perl and `Postgresql` packages enabled.

Then typed:

```
 /usr/bin/cygserver-config (This will install the service)
```

Then type:

```
net start cygserver(This starts the service)
```

Next i need to enable Postgresql in Cygwin, so i tried the commands mentioned below:

```
cygrunsrv -S cygserver

initdb -D /usr/share/postgresql/data

pg_ctl start -D /usr/share/postgresql/data -l /var/log/postgresql.log

createdb

psql
```

I get an error:

```
$ initdb -D /usr/share/postgresql/data
-bash: initdb: command not found

$ pg_ctl start -D /usr/share/postgresql/data -l /var/log/postgresql.log
-bash: pg_ctl: command not found
```

Can someone please tell me how to get it right.

Answer (score 13):

The Postgresql `initdb` and `pg_ctl` executables are located under `/usr/sbin`.

I am guessing that `/usr/sbin` is not on your `PATH` setting. Adding it should do the trick.

I use a start/stop script which I keep under `$HOME/bin` called `pg`. Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/buruzaemon/5351379).

Comment: I executed the first 3 commands, but once i execute  createdb. $ createdb database name
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: @sid, this sounds like a slightly different issue from the error reported in your original question. It would seem that `pg_ctl` has not even been started. You should check that first.

Comment: i started the pg_ctl service and it prints a server starting command. is there a way i could email u my doubt precisely with screen shots

Comment: Try foregoing your method of using a Windows service, and simply start the Cygwin server background process service with: `export CYGWIN=server; /usr/sbin/cygserver -E &`. Wait for `cygserver` to finish starting, and then try starting `pg_ctl`.

Comment: @TK-421, no worries, I am happy to hear that someone out there is making use of that script!

Comment: Also, I'm using it on OS X, so if anybody's looking for a simple Postgres/Mac script, just comment out the Cygwin stuff in the above gist.