# Ruby on Rails command rake db:migrate not working using PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, rake

As I mentioned in the title, I am using a PostgreSQL database on Ruby on Rails since heroku doesn't support MySQLite anymore. After I ran the command `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string` everything went smoothly, but when I tried `rake db:migrate` it throwed some errors. After searching for a while I downgraded Rake from 10.0.1 to 0.8.7. This is the error I get using --trace:

> ```
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32:
> Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config. (in /home/Roma/rails_projects/coise)
> ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
> ** Invoke environment (first_time)
> ** Execute environment
> ** Execute db:migrate rake aborted! could not connect to server: Connection refused
>         Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:928:in `initialize'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:928:in `new'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:928:in `connect'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:228:in `initialize'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:25:in `new'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:25:in `postgresql_connection'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `new_connection'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:238:in `checkout_new_connection'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:194:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `loop'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `block in checkout'
> /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:189:in `checkout'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `connection'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:318:in `retrieve_connection'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:486:in `initialize'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:433:in `new'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:433:in `up'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:415:in `migrate'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
> /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
> /usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
> /usr/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
> ```

I am really clueless of what to do now. I will also present my database.yml file (with some changes I made from the tips I encountered while searching):

```yaml
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: coise_development
  pool: 5
  username: coise
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: coise_test
  pool: 5
  username: coise
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: coise_production
  pool: 5
  username: coise
  password:
```

Comment: Is your posgresql server running? in linux you can start it using the command `sudo service postgresql start`

Comment: My machine is a Windows 7 but I am running Cygwin, I will try that.

Comment: As I thought. Service doesn't work on Cygwin. I'm sure I installed PostGreSQL using the Cygwin instalation, I just don't know how to run its commands...

Answer (score 1):

I have made progress. I was able, by this StackOverflow post - [Enable Postgresql in Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915952/enable-postgresql-in-cygwin) - to get my PostGreSql service up and running. In the end, all I had to do was change my *database.yml* file username and database fields according to the user on wich PostGreSql service started, in my case was "Roma".

Finally, the command `rake db:migrate` encountered no problems, just like my push to heroku did, flawless. The only thing I still don't understand lays on the heroku hosting, as my Users page (the table I added by using the Rails `scaffold` command) isn't available yet. My heroku tells me I should have more "Dynos" and upgrade to a "Production Postgresql Database". I'm not sure if this means that it will take a while for the hosting to complete or if there is actually anything wrong with my app, though I have to say that the database generated is really basic and simple.